# Convert nested lists to multidimensional array in R, preserving slice order

Tags: r, matlab

I need to export some data bidirectionally between R and Matlab, and the latter prefers arrays. I am trying to convert my R nested-list data structures into a multidimensional array before conversion to matlab, such that the slicing remains the same. This is (analogous to) what I am currently doing:

```
nestlist <- lapply(1:2, function(x) lapply(1:3, function(y) lapply(1:4, function(z) paste(x, y, z, sep = ""))))
unlist(nestlist)
 [1] "111" "112" "113" "114" "121" "122" "123" "124" "131" "132" "133" "134"
[13] "211" "212" "213" "214" "221" "222" "223" "224" "231" "232" "233" "234"
> length(nestlist)
[1] 2
> length(nestlist[[1]])
[1] 3
> length(nestlist[[1]][[1]])
[1] 4
```

As you can see, dimensions are 2x3x4 as expected. Now:

```
> ar <- array(unlist(nestlist), c(2, 3, 4))
> nestlist[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "111"
> ar[1,1,1]
[1] "111"
```

so far so good, but....

```
> nestlist[[2]][[2]][[3]]
[1] "223"
> ar[2,2,3]
[1] "214"
```

So somehow array creation is not happening in the same order as the list is parsed with unlist. How can I do this efficiently, preserving the indexing orders and dimensions? I'd like avoid nested sapplies etc ("manual" parsing) if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generalization of the transpose (`t`) function for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
tarray <- function(x) aperm(x, rev(seq_along(dim(x))))
```

Then you can define `ar` as follows:

```
ar <- tarray(array(unlist(nestlist), c(4, 3, 2)))
ar[2,2,3]
# [1] "223"
```